# How to search for some punctuations before a closing tag?

Tags: c#, regex

I have some text in the file as

```
<title>Dhind</title>
<title>WT.</title>
<title>Plant Leaves:</title>
<title>Denia;</title>
<title>Erod&#x00E9;</title>
```

I'm trying to find out whether there are dot, comma, semicolon or colon just before the closing tag `</title>` in my file except when there is a semi-colon which does not represent a 4 digit hex entity....i.e. the search should find the below results

```
<title>WT.</title>
<title>Plant Leaves:</title>
<title>Denia;</title>
```

and not `<title>Erod&#x00E9;</title>` as the "**;**" is part of the entity code so that is ignored.

I'm currently using this regex `string pattern = @"([.,:]|((?<!&#x\w{4});))</title>"` and doing a match with it.

Is there a more efficient regex pattern to do this, I'm not very good at regex...

**Note**: The file is not a valid xml or html, so xml/html parsing technique is not useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this regex should do the trick:

```
(?<!&#x[0-9a-fA-F]{4});(?=<\/title>)|([,.:])(?=<\/title>)
```

see here

> https://regex101.com/r/GSYf0w/1

Comment: you did not use `&#` in the expression, won't that cause a problem?

Comment: sorry, my bad: try now

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
<title>.*(?:\.|,|:|;)(?<!&#x[0-9a-fA-F]{4};)<\/title>
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s3PV35/1)

Explanation:

- matches the characters  literally (case sensitive)
- .* matches any character (except for line terminators)
- * Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Non-capturing group (?:.|,|:|;)
- 1st Alternative .
- \. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
- 2nd Alternative ,
- , matches the character , literally (case sensitive)
- 3rd Alternative :
- : matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
- 4th Alternative ;
- ; matches the character ; literally (case sensitive)
- Negative Lookbehind (?

  Assert that the Regex below does not match

  &#x matches the characters &#x literally (case sensitive)

  Match a single character present in the list below [0-9a-fA-F]{4}

  {4} Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times

  0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57) (case sensitive)

  a-f a single character in the range between a (index 97) and f (index 102) (case sensitive)

  A-F a single character in the range between A (index 65) and F (index 70) (case sensitive)

  ; matches the character ; literally (case sensitive)

  < matches the character < literally (case sensitive)

  / matches the character / literally (case sensitive)

  title> matches the characters title> literally (case sensitive)